# PHP call to Python script (via shell_exec() ) on Windows XAMPP

Tags: python, php, xampp

For testing reasons, I'm moving a small application from a VPS server to XAMPP. At first, I've run a test.py (that works):

```
#! C:/Users/{myUserDir}/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python310/python.exe
print("Content-Type: text/html\n")
print("Hello, World!")
```

After this, I wanted to test calls to Python from a PHP script, by uploading two scripts, taken from the net:

example.php

```
<?php
   echo "example";
   $command = escapeshellcmd('python C:\xampp\htdocs\example.py');
   $output = shell_exec($command);
   echo $output;
?>
```

example.py

```
#! C:/Users/{user}/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python310/python.exe
print("Content-Type: text/html\n")
print("<html>")
print("<h1>Something.</h1>")
```

In the error log, I can read:

*Python was not found; run without arguments to install from the Microsoft Store, or disable this shortcut from Settings > Manage App Execution Aliases.*

After disabling the App execution files, the error is:

**'C:\xampp\htdocs\example.py' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.**

I think the problem is in the #! string. Can anyone help me?